# Cactus Identification: miniature branching species with reddish areolas

Tags: identification, cactus, succulents

[image]
[image]

This is an approximately 10-year-old specimen of mine. I had a wild guess that it was a Frailea, but having looked at [all the recognized species of the genus](http://cactiguide.com/cactus/?genus=Frailea), I didn't find any that looks like it. Does anyone have an idea what this might be?

**Update:** It has bloomed this spring and the ID can be confirmed. It is indeed ***Rebutia heliosa***. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: So you've had it for 10 years? Have you observed any flowering on it at all? If so, what shape/color were the flowers, and where did they emerge on the stems?

Comment: Thanks for the update! It's always fun to see what happens to a plant we've been asked about. It looks healthy and beautiful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its Rebutia heliosa, though I've never seen quite such bulbous ends on one, but that may be due to its maturity, or the fact that most of the ones I've seen have several stems in the same pot, so the (comparative) slimness of the bases is not quite so obvious. Worth checking images and comparing though.

Comment: Does look like it. *Rebutia heliosa* is a strong offsetter, and over time the plants can become wide (almost mat-like). Perhaps people removed most of the offsets on this as they grew... Also, *R. heliosa* is a profuse flowerer in the spring (day length sensitive). I'll ask if the OP has seen any flowers, and what they looked like.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I saw the flowers and it fits! Thank you